# implementing a Stream Builder in Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, go, caching, request

i'am building a mobile app (Flutter/Golang), and i need to implemente a Stream builder for a live changing of a field in my Database.

So my question is : what DB/Caching-system to choose in order to support 60 requests per 500ms for exemple without having crashs everywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: What is a "stream builder"? You appear to use this term as if it's some sort of a standard technique, but I, for one, did not ever hear of it.

Comment: [This](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)? I mean a `StreamBuilder` class from the Flutter libs?

Comment: If my guess is correct, another guess would be to note that `StreamBuilder` instances consume events from instances of other classes which implement [`Stream`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream-class.html), and its manual page sites a bunch of concrete classes which implement `Stream`: CustomStream, ElementStream, HttpClientResponse, HttpRequest, HttpServer, LazyStream, RawDatagramSocket, RawSecureServerSocket, RawServerSocket, RawSocket, ReceivePort, SecureServerSocket, ServerSocket, Socket, Stdin, StreamView, StreamZip, SubscriptionStream, WebSocket…

Comment: …and I would say, of these, `HttpRequest` and `WebSocket` looks particularly worth further investigation.